# Получение кодов ссылок

Tags: python-3.x

я новичок, написал такой код (пытаюсь искать все битые сылки на сайте)

```
import requests
import re

r = requests.get("https://google.ru/")
All_links = re.findall('https?://(?:[-\w.]|(?:%[\da-fA-F]{2}))+', r.text)
print(All_links)

a = []
for links in All_links:
    a.append(requests.get(links).status_code)

print(a)
```

Когда обращаюсь на гугл, он все точно делает, когда обращаюсь к другим ресурсам и там куча ссылок, то он не дает мне проверить, я понимаю, что это сервер не дает, подскажите плз, как быть и куда копать

Comment: У меня все ссылки вывело и проблем не было, но наверняка если часто вызывать это, то гугл начнет капчу подсовывать

Comment: я и пишу, что с гугла норм все, вот если другой ресурс вбить то проблемы, к примеру mail.ru @gil9red

Comment: Это нужно в вопросе показывать. И не понятно, что у вас там с другим сайтом не так. Добавьте, пожалуйста, в вопрос, кнопка `править` под вопросом

Comment: Простите бога ради, так я ведь указал это в вопросе под самим кодом))))  @gil9red

Comment: Про другие ресурсам это очень неопределенно. Если вы не можете предоставить [минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), то на ваш вопрос будет очень сложно ответить, например, то что у вас подходит под это, но раз вы пожаловались про другие ресурсы, то укажите их и покажите в вопросе что не так

Comment: Теперь по теме, `requests` при отправке использует свой `User-Agent` вместо какого-то браузерного в заголовке запроса, уже это может заставить сайт отклонить запрос по любой надуманной причине или подсунуть капчу. Кроме того, сайт отправляют куки, поэтому возможно вам лучше использовать `requests.Session()`, хотя бы знать про него будет полезно.

Comment: Большое спасибо, буду разбираться, пробовать))) @gil9red